# Activate autofocus for tango color camera

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus, tango

How can I activate the autofocus of the tango color camera? The `TangoCameraIntrinsics` and `TangoConfig` classes of `com.google.atap.tangoservice` don't seem to have an option for doing it. I would like scan bar codes of products e.g. grocery items. To get a high resolution of the bar code, the product has to be close to the camera without having blur. I'm looking for a solution that works in C++ as well as in Java.

[blur on bar code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDIW4.png)

Answer (score 2):

The Tango tracker explicitly disables autofocus when it starts the camera capture session in order to run tracking correctly.  Unfortunately, there is not a setting to enable this through the SDK at this time.